# org.ros.android.app_chooser

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Is there a way to get the android.app_chooser.apk file from the developers of this android application?

I am trying to get the app on a android virtual device but cannot get on the android market with this AVD.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11906/org.ros.android.app_chooser/) by [Evert_Jans](https://answers.ros.org/users/1363/evert_jans/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-11-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This information is available on the wiki: http://ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0